# Continuity and increasing functions

Tags: analysis, continuity

Suppose $f : D \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous at the point $x_0 \in D$. Prove that:

1) if $f(x_0) > 0 $ then $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t.  $|x-x_0| < \delta $ & $x \in D \implies f(x) >0$;
2) if $f(x_0) < 0 $ then $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t.  $|x-x_0| < \delta $ & $x \in D \implies f(x) <0$;

I've constructed an answer but it seems a little too simple to be true so would like a check,

proof;

since $f$ is continuious we know that given some positive $\epsilon$ $\exists \delta > 0 $ s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta $ & $x\in D \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$,

since this is true for any epsilon set $\epsilon = |f(x_0)| $ then following the definition we have $|f(x) - f(x_0) | < |f(x_0)|$

$f(x_0) - |f(x_0)| < f(x) < |f(x_0)| + f(x_0)$ so for case 1, $|f(x_0)| = f(x_0)$ as $f(x_0) > 0 $ so $0=f(x_0) - |f(x_0)| < f(x)$ which proves 1), and for 2) $|f(x_0) = -f(x_0)$ so $f(x) < |f(x_0)| + f(x_0) = 0$ which proves 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the answer is correct and it should be a simple answer since the statement you are trying to proof is simple as well. If $f(x)$ above zero at $x_0$ and it is continuous then for some small neighborhood of $x_0$ it better be also above zero...